# If statement in CompiledQueries Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically, I want to execute the same query with different parameters based on a flag. 
For eg, The following is the case when my flag is true:-

```
private static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, string, IQueryable<DAL.ViewType>> GetFuncComponentsByLibID =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext dCtx, int libID, string searchText) =>
            (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes 
                where r.LibraryID == libID &&
                        r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                        r.TypeAttrStatus == null
                select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
                select k));
```

I want to execute the same query without the libID parameter if my flag is false.

```
private static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, string, IQueryable<DAL.ViewType>> GetFuncComponentsByLibID =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext dCtx, int libID, string searchText) =>
            (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes 
                where r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                        r.TypeAttrStatus == null
                select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
                select k));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is "or"ing your criteria with flag.

```
... (!flag || r.LibraryID == libID) ...
```

If flag is false, compared value will give you true.

Also this is possible:

```
private static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, string, IQueryable<DAL.ViewType>> GetFuncComponentsByLibID =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext dCtx, int libID, string searchText) => {
        if(flag)
            return (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes 
            where r.LibraryID == libID &&
                    r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                    r.TypeAttrStatus == null
            select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
            select k);
        else
            return (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes 
            where r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                    r.TypeAttrStatus == null
            select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
            select k);
    });
```

And another one:

```
private static Func<DataClassesDataContext, int, string, IQueryable<DAL.ViewType>> GetFuncComponentsByLibID =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DataClassesDataContext dCtx, int libID, string searchText) => {
        Func<ViewTypeAttributes, bool> whereFunc;
        if(flag)
            whereFunc = new Func<ViewTypeAttributes, bool>(r => r.LibraryID == libID &&
                    r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                    r.TypeAttrStatus == null);
        else
            whereFunc = new Func<ViewTypeAttributes, bool>(r => r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                    r.TypeAttrStatus == null);

        return (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes.Where(whereFunc)
            select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
            select k);
    });
```

Comment: I get compiler Errors saying `Only Assignment, Call, Increment and Decrement can be used as a statement` and `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree` Both are for first one.

Comment: I get compiler Errors saying `Only Assignment, Call, Increment and Decrement can be used as a statement` for the first one and `A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree` Both are for the second one. The inclusion of flag in libID doesn't work either as its returning wrong results.

Comment: Sorry the inclusion logic works ( instead of ! I used without it)but i have a question on that. As far as i know the or is left associative , meaning evaluates left and if true short circuits right one. But how its working right now though its true will it still evaluate right one?

Comment: if flag is false, then it should evaluate second one (since flag is "not"ted). Can you post where part here, so I can tell? Maybe it's about pharenteses etc)

Comment: So, this compiled Query works as expected..`
        CompiledQuery.Compile((LibMgmtDataClassesDataContext dCtx, int libID, string searchText, bool _searchAllLibs) =>
                (from k in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes
                 where (from r in dCtx.ViewTypeAttributes
                        where (_searchAllLibs || r.LibraryID == libID) &&
                        r.TypeAttributeValue.Contains(searchText) &&
                        r.TypeAttrStatus == null
                        select r.TypeID).Contains(k.TypeID)
                 select k));`

Comment: In the above code, if we pass _searchAllLibs as true, then it shouldn't compare or evaluate LibID (Second Operand) . Not sure how this gonna evaluate

Comment: Your code is ok, and should work as expected. What is the problem here? Is it still filtering by library id even if you pass _searchAllLibs as true?

Comment: Ohh i think i understood the execution now.very grateful for your effort

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)